# Play background music with DirectSound

Tags: c#, vb.net, directx, directsound

I'm using DirecSound to play sounds in my app because I need it to be able to play multiple sounds at the same time. However, when I alt-tab or even click on any other window the sound stops playing. Can I make it play in the background, even if the app has not focus?

The code I'm using is basically this:

```
Dim soundDevice As New Device
soundDevice.SetCooperativeLevel(Me.Handle, CooperativeLevel.Normal)
Dim sb As New SecondaryBuffer(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("MyFile.wav"), soundDevice)
sb.play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, thank you so much @user3560941 for answering my question with another question :) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223028/change-directsound-behavior)

The answer is to create a BufferDescription and set its flags to DSBCAPS_GLOBALFOCUS:

```
Dim soundDevice As New Device
soundDevice.SetCooperativeLevel(Me.Handle, CooperativeLevel.Normal)
Dim bd As New BufferDescription
bd.Flags = BufferDescriptionFlags.GlobalFocus
Dim sb As New SecondaryBuffer(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("MyFile.wav"), bd, soundDevice)
sb.play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default)
```